# Can't change custom option price or/and price type

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, price, custom-options

Well I went through all possible questions and answers. I can change any value regarding a custom option except for the price. Below is my code.

```
$oProd = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(theId);

$values = array();
foreach ($oProd->getOptions() as $o) {
   $p = $o->getValues();
   if($o->getTitle() == 'a specific custom option') {
       foreach($p as $v)
       {
           $values[$v->getId()]['title']= $v->getTitle();
           if($v->getTitle() == 'a value') {
                $values[$v->getId()]['price']= 10.0000;
           }
           else {
                $values[$v->getId()]['price']= $v->getPrice();
           }

           $values[$v->getId()]['store_id']=0;
           $values[$v->getId()]['option_type_id']= $v->getId();
           $values[$v->getId()]['option_type_price_id']= $v->getId();
           $values[$v->getId()]['sku']= $v->getSku();

           $v->setValues($values);
           $v->saveValues();

           if($v->getTitle() == 'a value') {
               // here I can see my updated price correctly.
               echo $v->getPrice();
           }
        }
   }
}

$oProd->save();
```

This does not update the product custom option price. I can however change title, sku, etc. What is the problem? Thank you!

#### Update:

The price and the price type are both stored under the table `catalog_product_option_type_price` in the database. It seems that I can't change any data on that table. I don't know why though.

Might be related: From Magento Admin > System > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Price > Changing to "Website", I see my price changed (through getPrice()), however this does not make a change on neither database nor Magento Admin.

Comment: same issue here in magento 2.x